# VPN Server on Windows Server 2008 Ent

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, remote-access

I'm creating a VPN Server on a 2008 Box I have but client connection hangs on Verifying Username and Password then provides error 800. Firewall is ruled out as I disabled it to test it and it can successfully connect locally on 127.0.0.1.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 does not use the firewall and what is your network config? what VPN config? different configs = different potential reasons.

Comment: Testing it locally so,
NIC Config:
> IP: 10.0.0.3
> Subnet: 255.255.254.0
> GW 10.0.0.1
|| Client:
> IP: 10.0.0.3
> Subnet and GW same.
Firewall exceptions to allow but firewall has been turned off to test. Any other specific information you might need let me know.

Comment: YOu still do not say what VPN technology. RRAS has multiple you can choose, you know.